# Equation of perpendicular to ellipsoid

Tags: 3d, geometry, trigonometry

I have an oblate ellipsoid (x^2+y^2)/a^2+z^2/b^2 and a point in ths space P(xp, xp, xp).

I need find the equation of perpendicular to ellipsoid from P and then the coordinates of intersection between ellipsoid and this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For oblate ellipsoid we can make simplification - solve 2D problem for ellipse with axes `a` and `b` and point with coordinates `P2=(Sqrt(px^2 + py^2), pz)`, then transform found point C2(x,y) to 3D as

```
C = (x*cos(f), x*sin(f), y)
where 
f = arctan2(py, px)
```

Perpendicular from point to ellipse intersects it in the closest point.
Let's write ellipse equation through angular parameter t

```
E(t)= (a * cos(t), b * sin(t))
```

Min.distance/normal condition leads to equation

```
D' = E'(t) * (E(t) - P2) = 0 (dot product)
-a^2 * cos(t) * sin(t) + p2.x * a * sin(t) + b^2 * cos(t) * sin(t) - p2.y * b * cos(t) = 0
```

to solve it for t, at first check if cos(t)=0 is solution. If not, divide by cos(t)

```
-a^2 * sin(t) + p2.x * a * tg(t) +  b^2 * sin(t) - p2.y * b = 0
```

then substitute sin and tg through p=[half-angle tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) and solve 4th degree equation.

```
p = tg(t/2)
-a^2 * 2 * p / (1 + p^2) + p2.x * a * 2 * p /(1 - p^2) + 
 b^2 * 2 * p / (1 + p^2) - p2.y * b = 0

-a^2 * 2 * p * (1 - p^2) + p2.x * a * 2 * p * (1 + p^2) + 
 b^2 * 2 * p * (1 - p^2) - p2.y * b * (1 - p^4)= 0
```

There are two roots for points outside ellipse (and up to 4 roots for internal points, not sure what might happen in 3D). Choose proper one (closest point). Transform 2D case to 3D as described.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient at any point is `(2X/a²,2Y/a²,2Z/b²)`, which must be parallel to `(Xp,Yp,Zp)`. Then `X/a²Xp=Y/a²Yp=Z/b²Zp`.

Eliminating `X` and `Y`,

```
(Z.a²Xp/b²Zp)²/a² + (Z.a²Yp/b²Zp)²/a² + Z²/b² = 1.
```

gives you `Z`.

---

**Update**:

As pointed by @dmuir, the line isn't through the origin, and parallelism must be to `(X-Xp,Y-Yp,Z-Zp)`.

This gives `X/a²(X-Xp)=Y/a²(Y-Yp)=Z/b²(Z-Zp)`. `X` and `Y` can still be eliminated but are an homographic function of `Z`. The final equation in `Z` is quartic, I guess.

Comment: I don't think the gradient will, in general,  be parallel to the vector from the centre to the point. That is true for spheres, but not for ellipsoids.

Comment: @dmuir: quite right. For some silly reason, I kept thiking that the line went throught the origin :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex. In the usual (geodetic) lat,long,height coordinate system the height is indeed the distance along the normal to the ellipsoid. So what you want is part of the conversion from ECEF (ie x,y,z) coordinates to geodetic coordinates. This is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) for example